# EF5: Unused and unknown column causes problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, entity, entity-framework-5

Ok, so I have 2 entities: Course and Industry

[image: Course and Industry Entities]

The industry entity is just a reference table which lists all available Industries that can be tagged to a course, to categorizing them. I put in a many to zero or one relationship (a course can choose to have an industry or not, while an industry can be tagged with many courses).

I know I've played around with the diagrams a bit, adding and removing associations in the past.

**Now here is the odd part: The column mappings for Course has 2 similar columns, IndustryId and Industry_Id**

[image: Odd Course Column Mapping]

I suspect it's from a past association, but thought EF would have taken care of that.

**Here is the problem:**

In my view that creates the course, the IndustryId is the property which needs to be populated. When I create new courses, I see the IndustryId in the database populated.

However, when I access Industry's properties through Course (Course.Industry.Description) nothing is populated. It can't seem to get the Industry entity.

**I see the IndustryId populated in the db, so I tried to populate the Industry_Id column. That fixed it.**

Weird enough, the property declared in the model is IndustryId, so that column is populated in the db. But when I try to get Industry entities through Course, it needs the Industry_Id, which I don't quite know where it is from.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Utilize lazy loading by making your navigation properties virtual, or, using the fluent API, eager load by using the `.Include()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like in your updating from the database, you changed the column name on your tables from `Industry_Id` to `IndustryId`. The next time you updated from the database, EF5 (which can't determine that this is the same column, as it matches on names) dropped the mapping for `Industry_Id`, and added a new column called `IndustryId`.

However, you had already created the foreign-key mapping in your EDMX file based on the `Industry_Id` column - which is why you get the issue around needing it when loading related records.

In general, when using Database-First, whenever you rename a column in the database, you need to update your EF5 model and update / correct any such discrepancies.